# HTML image tag weird behavior

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have React project and I use icons inside `img` tag the icons are big, so I adjust their `width`, but the `img` tag affect the others element width here some screenshots:

the `icon` without any styling:

[image]

now add set the  height 100% and the width 10%:

[image]

and now I remove the `img`:

[image]

you see the the `icon` got smaller but it wide

here the App.tsx code

```
import React from "react";
import CardComp from "./components/CardComp";
import cook from "./assets/cooking.png";
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-[100vh] w-[100vw]">
      <CardComp placeholder="test" image={cook} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and the CardComp:

```
import React from "react";

interface ICard {
  placholder: string;
  image: string;
}
const CardComp: React.FC<ICard> = ({ placeholder, image }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bg-fuchsia-300 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
        <div className="debug ">
          <img src={image} className="w-[10%] h-[100%]" />
        </div>
        <h3>{placeholder}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardComp;
```

how can I adjust the `icon` without this weird behavior.
I use Tailwind for the styling.

Comment: can you try with `h-auto` instead of `h-[100%]` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for some images you dont need to set the height,width is enough to edit the size of the image
try **width:50px**

Comment: It really worked, but why when I set the width in percentage give different result comparison to fixed value like `px` and `em`?

Answer (score 1):

%,px and em values in html differ from each other